# Почему jsp не понимает css а с html-ем все нормально?

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

**CSS:**

[image: CSS]

**html:**

[image: html]

**Итог:**

[image: Итог]

**это в JSP:**

[image: JSP]

**а это результат JSP:**

[image: а это результат JSP]

**Вопрос:** почему JSP не понимает CSS файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что нужно указавать путь контекста `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` в URL к стилю.

Вот примерно как должен выглядеть код

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное ...получилось супер спасибо еще раз